# Removing items from a container using javaScript to display new sort order

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple page, using bootstrap and js/jquery. It fetchs data via ajax and creates entries to be displayed to viewer, something like:

-make request

-parse xml creating array of objects containing all data

-sort by one property

create DOM elements and appendsTo proper parent.

All goes fine so far.

Now, with a button user can change the property to sort the arrays.

I did:

```
//deputados is the array, partido the property 
deputados.sort(sort_by('partido', true, function (a) {
        return deaccentuate0(a);//get rid of accents for sorting
    }));

//here i create nodes in new order
for (var i = 0; i < deputados.length; i++) {
        makePanelEntry($("#containerMaster"), deputados[i])
    };
});
```

Obviously the new items are being appended to the end of the list and that's not what I want, they should replace existing elements in the page.(creation and append are handled by makePanelEntry() do you need to see this?).

The question is:

Is there a way to clean all elements from a container(containerMaster) at once? Do I need to loop trough it and remove one by one? Is this the correct approach for doing this?

I'm very new in all that.
thanks

[EDIT 2]:
this is how I'm creating the elements:
basically it creates elements for a bootstrap "panel" in the proper order and with the proper classes, then in the switch, populates the panels with each deputado proper value. If name create according div with name tag and so on. Those are congressman data :P

deputado is this:

```
var deputado = {
            idCadastro: $(this).find("ideCadastro").text(),
            condicao: $(this).find("condicao").text(),
            matricula: $(this).find("matricula").text(),
            idParlamentar: $(this).find("idParlamentar").text(),
            nome: $(this).find("nome").text(),
            nomeParlamentar: $(this).find("nomeParlamentar").text(),
            sexo: $(this).find("sexo").text(),
            uf: $(this).find("uf").text(),
            partido: $(this).find("partido").text(),
            gabinete: $(this).find("gabinete").text(),
            anexo: $(this).find("anexo").text(),
            fone: $(this).find("fone").text(),
            email: $(this).find("email").text(),
            //comissoes: $(this).find("comissoes").text(),,    
            print_name: function () {
                console.log(deaccentuate0(this.nome));
            }
        };
```

function makePanelEntry:

```
var makePanelEntry = function (parent, deputado) {
    var elements = [];
    var outter = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "panel panel-default"
    }).appendTo(parent);

    var heading = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "panel-heading"
    }).appendTo(outter);

    var title = $('<h3/>', {
        "class": "panel-title"
    }).appendTo(heading);

    var row = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "row"
    }).appendTo(title);

    var body = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "panel-body",
    }).appendTo(outter);

    var bodyRow = $('<div/>', {
        "class": "row",
    }).appendTo(body);



    $.each(deputado, function (prop, val) {
        if (typeof val !== 'function') {
            switch (prop) {

            case "nomeParlamentar":
                var np = $('<div/>', {
                    'class': "col-md-3 ",
                    text: val
                });
                elements[0] = np;
                break;

            case "partido":
                var p = $('<div/>', {
                    'class': "col-md-1",
                    text: val
                })
                elements[1] = p;
                break;

            case "uf":
                var u = $('<div/>', {
                    'class': "col-md-1",
                    text: val
                })
                elements[2] = u;
                break;

            case "nome":
                var smallDiv = $('<div/>', {
                    'class': "col-md-3 italic smaller",
                    text: val
                }).appendTo(bodyRow);
                break;

            case "fone":
                $('<div/>', {
                    "class": "col-md-2 text-left",
                    text: "fone:  61 - " + val
                }).appendTo(bodyRow)
                break;

            case "condicao":
                var cond = $('<div/>', {
                    "class": "col-md-2 text-left",
                    text: val
                }).appendTo(bodyRow)
                elements[3] = cond;
                break;

            case "email":
                $('<a/>', {
                    "class": "col-md-2 text-left",
                    text: val,
                    href: "mailto:" + val
                }).appendTo(bodyRow)
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

    })
    $.each(elements, function (i, e) {
        $(e).appendTo(row)
    })
};
```

and sort_by is this (grabbed somewhere):

```
var sort_by = function (field, reverse, primer) {
    var key = function (x) {
        return primer ? primer(x[field]) : x[field]
    };

    return function (a, b) {
        var A = key(a),
            B = key(b);
        return ((A < B) ? -1 : ((A > B) ? 1 : 0)) * [-1, 1][+ !! reverse];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clear all children of a parent with the jQuery method [`.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) as in `$("#containerMaster").empty()`.

When sorting, you often don't have to create entirely new nodes.  You can just move the existing nodes into the proper order.  I don't understand the functions in your code that there is no source for so I can't offer a more specific way to do that, but sorting does not generally need to create new nodes.

Comment: Great! that did it! Well how would i move the elements created? As I said I'm noob and using all this to study, so I may be doing something really stupid. I'll edit the question with the code for creating my panes so you can see. Thanks

Comment: To sort your existing HTML, I would be easier to see a representative sample of the generated HTML as that would be a lot simpler than trying to figure out exactly what `makePanelEntry()` creates.  I also need to know what's in `deputado` and how `sort_by()` works.  If that's too much work, then just stick with what you already have working.

Comment: Never to much work for help :) the page as it is (shame - it is my testing page) is here: kubrusly.com/yxd/bootStrap/deput_copy.html to sort click any button (for now) and others infos u asked are in the question reedited. thanks!!